# Get index of element in "element_view_for" helper in Alchemy CMS

Tags: alchemy-cms

I want to use a bootstrap 5 carousel in an alchemy element with nested images. In order to do this, i need to get the sortorder or index of the iteration, as the carousel expects an "active" tag on the first element.

```
  <%= element_view_for(image_slide, tag: false) do |el| %>
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <%= el.render :image, {}, class: "d-block w-100 #{"active" if index == 0}" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every Rails partial that rendered by the collection renderer you have a local variable called `<the-partial-name>_counter` available.

From https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#local-variables

> Rails also makes a counter variable available within a partial called
> by the collection, named after the title of the partial followed by
> _counter. For example, when rendering a collection @products the partial _product.html.erb can access the variable product_counter
> which indexes the number of times it has been rendered within the
> enclosing view. Note that it also applies for when the partial name
> was changed by using the as: option. For example, the counter variable
> for the code above would be item_counter.

Just make sure that the parent element (I'm assuming an `imager_slider`) uses the collection partial renderer.

```
[...]
  <%= render image_slider.nested_elements.published %>
[...]
```

Then you can use

```
<%= element_view_for(image_slide, tag: false) do |el| %>
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <%= el.render :image, {}, class: "d-block w-100 #{"active" if image_slide_counter == 1}" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```